# segmentation fault due to strcpy()

Tags: c

why am i getting segmentation fault in strcpy()?

the program gets compiled without any problem but
i am getting a segmentation fault because of strcpy please suggest me a way out.

```
struct obj
{
    char objcode[100];
}o[10];

int main()
{
    char buffer[500],statement[50][50];/*storing each statement*/
    int i=0,fd;
    int j=0,k=0;
    char *tok;
    fd=open("objectprogram.txt",O_RDONLY);
    const ssize_t r=read(fd,buffer,500);
    buffer[r]='\0';
    char *sta;
    sta=strtok(buffer,"\n");
    while(sta!=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(statement[i],sta);
        i++;
        sta=strtok(NULL,"\n");
    }   
    for(j=1;j<i-1;j++)
    {
        tok=strtok(statement[j],"^");
        tok=strtok(NULL,"^"); 
        tok=strtok(NULL,"^");
        while(tok!=NULL)
        {
            tok=strtok(NULL,"^");
            strcpy(o[k].objcode,tok);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use valgrind for debugging

Comment: Do some basic debugging first. e.g. print out the value of `j`, `k` and `tok` so you can see if they're something you don't expect them to be when the program crash

Comment: AS this isn't a compiling example, try running it through valgrind and see what it says.  Make sure to compile with `-g` to get debug info in the object code, and then `valgrind a.out` or whatever your program name is.

Comment: There is a total lack of error-checking in your code.

Comment: You should provide objectprogram.txt so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your check for `tok==NULL` in the `while` loop happens *after* the call to `strcpy`, not before. You're trying to copy a NULL pointer.

Whenever you get a segmentation fault, the first thing to look for is the possibility of a NULL pointer.

Comment: as you said the null pointer is causing problem how to resolve?

Comment: @user305774 just rearrange things to do them in the proper order.

Comment: following code worked:
   
          `while(tok!=NULL)`  
   `{`  
  `tok=strtok(NULL,"^");`  
  `if(tok!=NULL)`  
  `{`  
   `strcpy(o[k++].objcode,tok);`  
  `}`  
  `}`

Comment: @user305774 sure that would work, but it's the awkward way to do it.

Comment: @user305774 because the null pointer didn't point to valid memory. You're lucky it didn't, the standard doesn't require it to work that way; it helps your debugging when you get a crash like that instead of just a silent wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
                    while(tok!=NULL)
                    {
                        tok=strtok(NULL,"^");
                        strcpy(o[k].objcode,tok);
                    }
```

You check for `tok`'s validity before entering the loop but not after it gets changed by `strtok()`.

A debugger should have been able to identify exactly which line of code had the problem, and from within the debugger you could see if the value of `tok` is okay or not at the time `strcpy()` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

strcpy is not safe in terms of array size, use strncpy instead!!

i.e. if you get more data in your input, you will overflow your statement[i].